# Plot wavewform in Tkinter (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, audio, tkinter

Does anyone know how to display the waveform of a sound file in a Tkinter window (Python)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you attempted to write any code? Where have you looked for documentation?

Comment: I've not started at all yet!

Comment: See this link. It learn how to plot waveform in Tkinter. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-embed-matplotlib-charts-in-tkinter-gui/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the sound file format, if it is a .wav then you can probably just read it in to a numpy array then plot it, otherwise you are going to have to parse the file format first.

Comment: @SF12Study: Take a look at https://www.audiolabs-erlangen.de/resources/MIR/FMP/B/B_PythonAudio.html for an example.